# explain the working of overflow while using flexbox to create a page layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am making a simple page layout with one header, one side-bar, and the rest of the area for the main content. check the below image. And here is  the [codepen](https://codepen.io/hirenparekh/pen/MWeLELW) And I have pasted the code at the bottom too.

[image]

Let me highlight a few points regarding HTML and CSS of this page.

- Here site-wrapper has a height of 100vh and width of 100vw.
- site-wrapper has flex-direction: column
- site-wrapper has two children, header and content-wrapper.
- content-wrapper has a white border and it has two children side-bar and page-content
- **content-wrapper has overflow:hidden and page-content has overflow:auto**

This last point is important as my question is related to this point only.

Now if I remove the overflow:hidden property from the content-wrapper which is the direct parent of page-content then the page-content's overflow property does not work. Please check the below image.

[image]

This behaviour feels little tricky to me because I don't know what css rule is applied here.

how is setting overflow property on content-wrapper is interfering with the height calculation of page-content. (pardon me if this does not make sense)

The page-content's overflow will work if content-wrapper have either overflow:hidden or overflow:auto.

I need help to understand what is going on here.

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <header class="header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <aside class="side-bar">SIDEBAR</aside>
    <main class="page-content">
      <ul class="long-list">
        <li class="list-item">1</li>
        <li class="list-item">2</li>
        <li class="list-item">3</li>
        <li class="list-item">4</li>
        <li class="list-item">5</li>
        <li class="list-item">6</li>
        <li class="list-item">7</li>
        <li class="list-item">8</li>
        <li class="list-item">9</li>
        <li class="list-item">10</li>
        <li class="list-item">11</li>
        <li class="list-item">12</li>
      </ul>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background-color: #47cf73;
  padding:10px;
}

.header{
  height:60px;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
/*   overflow:hidden; */
}

.page-content{
  overflow: auto; /*this overflow only works
if its parent div (i.e .content-wrapper)
has overflow auto or hidden*/  
 flex:1;
  background-color: #FF7043;
  padding: 10px;
}

.side-bar{
  background-color: #FFEB3B;
  width: 30vw;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.long-list{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-item{
  font-size:36px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FF8A65;
  text-align: center;
}


.list-item:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```